# TypeScript syntax for "at least these properties"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to find the syntax to declare a type that has at least these properties, for example:

```
interface InspectedError {
  originalErrorObj: any,
  errorAsString: string,
  errorObjParsed: {
    message: string,
    stack: string
  }
}
```

the errorObjParsed value might have more properties, should I do this:

```
interface InspectedError {
  originalErrorObj: any,
  errorAsString: string,
  errorObjParsed: {
    message: string,
    stack: string,
    ...any
  }
}
```

there is the Partial<> construct, I am looking for like Subset<> or Superset<> construct, like this:

```
interface InspectedError {
  originalErrorObj: any,
  errorAsString: string,
  errorObjParsed: SupersetOf<{
    message: string,
    stack: string,
  }>
}
```

so that I could do:

```
const e = new Error('test');
e.foo = 'bar';

const v: InspectedError = {
   originalErrorObj: e,
   errorAsString: util.inspect(e),
   errorObjectParsed: {
      message: e.message,
      stack: e.stack,
      ...e
   }
}
```

and allow for any other arbitrary properties that might exist on `e`.

Comment: Given that excess property checks are only applied in certain circumstances, what's the actual problem with the first type?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Partial<x>  is like saying SubsetOf<x>, I would love a SupersetOf<x>  ... in this case I am not sure if the compiler complains, but in other cases it will complain about extra properties

Comment: In those cases they're properties that cannot be used, as the object is _only_ accessible via the narrower interface, so again why's it a _problem_? Maybe you just want [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of achieving this, but assuming you want to avoid one involving `class`es and sub`class`es, I'd suggest:

```
interface InspectedError {
  originalErrorObj: Error
  errorAsString: string
  errorObjParsed: {
    message: string
    stack: string
    [x: string]: any
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the `SuperSet<>` construct you asked for using an index signature like this. This tells TypeScript to assume that `errorObjParsed` could have *any* properties besides `message` and `stack`. The only problem is that accessing properties that don't actually exist on some hypothetical `e` will not give an error, and you won't get code completion for anything besides `message` and `stack`.

```
type SuperSet<T extends {}> = T & {[key: string]: any};

interface InspectedError {
  originalErrorObj: any,
  errorAsString: string,
  errorObjParsed: SuperSet<{
    message: string,
    stack: string
  }>
}
```

***Alternatively***

If you make `InspectedError` a generic type, then you can make `errorObjParsed` an intersection type. With this, you can safely access `message`, `stack`, *and* the properties of `e`.

```
interface InspectedError<T extends {} = {}> {
  originalErrorObj: any,
  errorAsString: string,
  errorObjParsed: T & {
    message: string,
    stack: string
  }
}

const v: InspectedError<typeof e> = {
   originalErrorObj: e,
   errorAsString: 'asd',
   errorObjParsed: {
      message: e.message,
      stack: e.stack,
      ...e
   }
}
```